# UnitTest -issue when testing method coming from mock

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

I'm having an class using an Interface that is having a void method looking like this witch is now the fully working method:

```
public void SellGivenQuantityOfProduct(Product product, int quantity)
{
    product.StockQuantity = product.StockQuantity - quantity;
}
```

But working the TDD-way, I started to do it like this below, but the calculation never happens in my test-method

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Can_Sell_Given_Quantity_Of_Single_Products_Stock_Quantity()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<ISellBuyPipeLine>();
        mock.Setup(o => o.Products).Returns(new Product[]
        {
            new Product() {ArticleNr = 87, StockQuantity = 10}
        });
        var product = mock.Object.Products.First();
        var choosenProductToSell = new SellBuyProduct() {Product = product, Quantity = 5};
        mock.Object.SellGivenQuantityOfProduct(product, choosenProductToSell.Quantity);

        /*var test = new SellBuyPipeLine();
        test.SellGivenQuantityOfProduct(product, choosenProductToSell.Quantity);*/

        int expectedSellValue = product.StockQuantity;

        Assert.AreEqual(5, expectedSellValue);
    }
```

If I'm using the outcommented lines and hits the class holding my method directly it works! But I want to use the mock.

What am I doing wrong?

Do I use the wrong approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your `Product` class contains actual business logic, don't mock it at all. I'd suggest pretending to be stupid when you write tests whenever you can.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Can_Sell_Given_Quantity_Of_Single_Products_Stock_Quantity()
{
    var product = new Product { ArticleNr = 87, StockQuantity = 10 };

    var pipeline = new SellBuyPipeLine();
    pipeline.SellGivenQuantityOfProduct(product, 5);

    Assert.AreEqual(5, product.StockQuantity);
}
```

Stupid(ly simple) tests lead to to stupidly simple production code and that is exactly what you want.

Avoid strict behavior for mocks and assertions on calls whenever you can as those make your tests brittle.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks for your answer! This Is the approach I was using first. And yes, my method does not holds any bussines-logic. Now to the question: Witch approach is the best to use: user bsrenzel vs user CodeCaster ?

Comment: The method you're testing `SellGivenQuantityOfProduct` should contain business logic. That's what you're testing to begin with. You just don't need to mock `Product` if it's just a data transfer object. What you actually mock are dependencies, i.e. another class holds a reference to an `ISellBuyPipeline` instance which is injected via the constructor. In that case you'd instantiate that class with a mocked object and not the real deal.

Comment: The method takes data from my db and changes it. Is that reffered to as buissness-logic?

Comment: Yes. That's not the point, though. The point is that you only test the functionality of the current class (`SellBuyPipeLine` in this case) in your unit tests. If `Product` had major functionality, you'd have to make sure that you can mock `Product` (e.g. by extracting an interface and change `SellBuyPipeLine` to depend on that interface), so can write a test against `SellBuyPipeLine` without testing `Product` at the same time.

Comment: Devil's advocate: an implementation of `product.StockQuantity = 5` will pass this test but not implement the requirement "decrease the StockQuantity by the given quantity".

Comment: Yes, you can't really expect to define and reach the final requirement(s) with a single test anyway. In TDD you code the most simple possible solution to pass the test too. If it were only this one test, you'd just hard-code the method to set the quantity to 5. For something like this I'd use test cases (I use NUnit) and a parameterized test method.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to test the implementation, test the implementation. The mock object's method does not contain an implementation.

You may want to mock the `Product`, making the test method looking something like this:

```
public void Can_Sell_Given_Quantity_Of_Single_Products_Stock_Quantity()
{
    // Arrange
    int stockQuantity = 10;
    int quantityToSell = 4;
    int newQuantity = 6;

    var productMock = new Mock<Product>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    productMock.SetupGet(p => p.StockQuantity).Returns(stockQuantity);
    productMock.SetupSet(p => p.StockQuantity = newQuantity);

    var classUnderTest = new SellBuyPipeLine();

    // Act
    test.SellGivenQuantityOfProduct(product, quantityToSell);

    // Assert
    productMock.VerifySet(p => p.StockQuantity, Times.Once());
}
```

You can do without though as the Product doesn't contain any logic, in that case just instantiate a `new Product` and assert its `StockQuantity` equals `newQuantity`;

Comment: Ok! Should I just test the lines I've commened out instead? Or what is the correct approach of doing it?

Comment: SellGivenQuantityOfProduct-method is in my Interface. Why is it wrong to test it trough the interface-mock? Or is it the wrong approach to have this method in my interface at all? Would it be better to put it in my Product-class instead?

Comment: Basically because you mock what you _don't_ want to test. You're testing the SellGivenQuantityOfProduct _implementation_.

Comment: Would it be better to put my method in my Product-class instead? Is it the wrong approach to have it in my interface?

Comment: No. It just means that if you want to test a class that _uses_ `ISellBuyPipeLine`, you can mock the `ISellBuyPipeLine`.

Comment: I'm getting a exeption on this line: `productMock.SetupGet(p => p.StockQuantity).Returns(stockQuantity);` . Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: p => p.StockQuantity

Comment: To mock a member (property or method), it needs to be virtual (virtual, abstract or override keyword on classes or interface members, which are implicitly abstract). You cannot mock a simple non-virtual property.

Comment: @bstenzel So the best approach would be to use your Aswer to the question? Seems like overdoing it by changing my method to virtual and stuff

Comment: In this case my answer is completely sufficient and simpler. So, yes, I do think it is the way to go.